# Neural Net Optimize w/ Genetic Algorithm

Tags: matlab, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

Is a genetic algorithm the most efficient way to optimize the number of hidden nodes and the amount of training done on an artificial neural network?

I am coding neural networks using the NNToolbox in Matlab.  I am open to any other suggestions of optimization techniques, but I'm most familiar with GA's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, there are multiple things that you can optimize using GA regarding NN.
You can optimize the structure (number of nodes, layers, activation function etc.).
You can also train using GA, that means setting the weights.

Genetic algorithms will never be the most efficient, but they usually used when you have little clue as to what numbers to use.

For training, you can use other algorithms including backpropagation, [nelder-mead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder-Mead_method) etc..

You said you wanted to optimize number hidden nodes, for this, genetic algorithm may be sufficient, although far from "optimal". The space you are searching is probably too small to use genetic algorithms, but they can still work and afaik, they are already implemented in matlab, so no biggie.

What do you mean by optimizing amount of training done? If you mean number of epochs, then that's fine, just remember that training is somehow dependent on starting weights and they are usually random, so the fitness function used for GA won't really be a function.

Comment: What is the benefit of training an ANN using GA over using only GP? ANNs have the benefit that they mimic a brain, and that they can use methods to update the weights in a smart way, such as backpropagation, to ensure that the network evolves in the right direction (just like in the brain). But when using GA to update the weights, you loose all that, and it doesn't seem to me like you have any real advantage over GP anymore, since it's now just up to chance if the network will improve or not. What is your take on that?

Answer (score 5):

A good example of neural networks and genetic programming is the NEAT architecture (Neuro-Evolution of Augmenting Topologies). This is a genetic algorithm that finds an optimal topology. It's also known to be good at keeping the number of hidden nodes down.

They also made a game using this called Nero. Quite unique and very amazing tangible results.

Dr. Stanley's homepage:

http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/

Here you'll find just about everything NEAT related as he is the one who invented it.

Comment: there's also a C# library for this --> SHARPNEAT http://sharpneat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Genetic algorithms can be usefully applied to optimising neural networks, but you have to think a little about what you want to do.

Most "classic" NN training algorithms, such as Back-Propagation, only optimise the weights of the neurons. Genetic algorithms can optimise the weights, but this will typically be inefficient. However, as you were asking, they can optimise the topology of the network and also the parameters for your training algorithm. You'll have to be especially wary of creating networks that are "over-trained" though.

One further technique with a modified genetic algorithms can be useful for overcoming a problem with Back-Propagation. Back-Propagation usually finds local minima, but it finds them accurately and rapidly. Combining a Genetic Algorithm with Back-Propagation, e.g., in a Lamarckian GA, gives the advantages of both. This technique is briefly described during the [GAUL tutorial](http://gaul.sourceforge.net/tutorial/nn.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes useful to use a genetic algorithm to train a neural network when your objective function isn't continuous.

Comment: Why not just use GP in that case? If you use GA to update the weights in the neural network, instead of some smart method that ensures the weights are all updated in the right direction, it seems like you loose the advantage of using a neural net over just using GP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you should use a genetic algorithm for this.

I suppose the initial solution population for your genetic algorithm would consist of training sets for your neural network (given a specific training method). Usually the initial solution population consists of random solutions to your problem. However, random training sets would not really train your neural network.

The evaluation algorithm for your genetic algorithm would be a weighed average of the amount of training needed, the quality of the neural network in solving a specific problem and the numer of hidden nodes.

So, if you run this, you would get the training set that delivered the best result in terms of neural network quality (= training time, number hidden nodes, problem solving capabilities of the network).

Or are you considering an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what kind of problem you're working with, but GA sounds like a little bit of overkill here. Depending on the range of parameters you're working with, an exhaustive (or otherwise unintelligent) search may work. Try plotting your NN's performance with respect to number of hidden nodes for a first few values, starting small and jumping by larger and larger increments. In my experience, many NNs plateau in performance surprisingly early; you may be able to get a good picture of what range of hidden node numbers makes the most sense.

The same is often true for NNs' training iterations. More training helps networks up to a point, but soon ceases to have much effect.

In the majority of cases, these NN parameters don't affect performance in a very complex way. Generally, increasing them increases performance for a while but then diminishing returns kick in. GA is not really necessary to find a good value on this kind of simple curve; if the number of hidden nodes (or training iterations) really does cause the performance to fluctuate in a complicated way, then metaheuristics like GA may be apt. But give the brute-force approach a try before taking that route.

Comment: brute force doesn't work for my application because my data is very noisy (think EEG data).

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to say that genetic algorithms is a good idea since you can start with a minimal solution and grow the number of neurons. It is very likely that the "quality function" for which you want to find the optimal point is smooth and has only few bumps.

If you have to find this optimal NN frequently I would recommend using optimization algorithms and in your case quasi newton as described in numerical recipes which is optimal for problems where the function is expensive to evaluate.